# Generalized Hamming Weights for Hermitian Codes

Tags: coding-theory

In the work of K. Yang PH.D thesis "On the Weight Hierarchy of Hermitian Codes and others Geometric Goppa Codes." It has the following result that I don't understand all step.

I would appreciate a help

I don't understand the claim: (d) follows from proposition 3.4...

[image]

Comment: I realize that it is difficult to make this self-contained, but presently the question is a bit difficult to follow. 1) which version of the Hermitian curve is considered here? My first guess would be $y^q-y=x^{q+1}$ over the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$, but IIRC some sources use a different one. 2) what is the relation between $m$ and $n$ in Prop. 4.1. 20 years ago I would have been able to deduce these bits from the details of the proof, but these pieces are no longer fresh :-)

Comment: Check out [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) for ways of using TeX on the site, and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for pointers about posing your question well.

Comment: Anyway, I dare guess the idea is that the range of values of $i$ in part (d) is such that the relevant part of the generalized Hamming weight spectrum of the dual code is easy to figure out. My guess is that a span of more or less obvious polynomials has the indicated support sizes.

Comment: I am not an expert on this, by any means. But I know Kyeongcheol Yang. He would answer an e-mail, if no answer is forthcoming here. See https://eee.postech.ac.kr/professor_type/yang-kyeongcheol/

Comment: ohh Thanks you all @JyrkiLahtonen and kodlu

Comment: LOL. I, too, met Kyeongcheol Yang in the 90s a couple of times. As well as his advisor, Jong-seon No (probably retired by now). I'm actually confident I could still work out the answer to this, but Proposition 4.1. feels a bit non-sensical without further context. It may still be faster to ask the author.